# Why can't I have two separate functions returning two different views simultaneously?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, view, laravel-blade

I'm playing around with Laravel but I'm having an issue with the controller returning views.  `$aboutUs` works but for `$footerText` I get an error that says:

```
Undefined variable: footerText (View: 
/Users/user/sublime/blog/resources/views/about- 
us.blade.php)
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's `AboutUsController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class AboutUsController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $aboutUs = "About Us";

        return view('about-us', compact("aboutUs"));
    }

    public function indexTwo()
    {
        $footerText = "Some more text here";

        return view('footer-content', compact("footerText"));
    }

}
```

Here's `views/about-us.bladephp`:

```
@extends('layouts.about-us')

@section('title', $aboutUs)

@section('about-content')
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{ $aboutUs }}</h1> {{-- This works --}}
        <h1>{{ $footerText  }}</h1> {{-- This doesn't work --}}
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Why not try to use one function instead?

Comment: @MONSTER you can't return two things in one function

Comment: Are you looking to return page specific footer data? Why not just create a layout template that holds your header and footer data and wrap your page specific content in that?

Answer (score 1):

In returning 2 things in a single function, try this using `with`.

```
public function index()
{
    $aboutUs = "About Us";
    $footerText = "Some more text here";


    return view('about-us', compact("aboutUs"))
              ->with('footer-content', compact("footerText"));
}
```